# How to implement MVVM design pattern with Xamarin.Forms PCL & Web API service

Tags: mongodb, web-services, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am developing an Xamarin application.

**My solution architecture:**

[image]

**Explain:**

1. MongoService - This is Web API service for talking with MongoDB (My database).
2. OpTeamizerApp - This is Xamarin.Forms PCL (Shared project).
3. OpTeamizerApp.Android - Default project for Android.
4. OpTeamizerApp.IOS - Default project for IOS.

Im using MVVM design pattern and OpTeamizerApp (PCL project) contains Views, View models.

Now, I want to create the Models (e.g Mobile etc.).

**So, my question:**
Where this Models need to be?

My opinion that the Models need to be with the Views, View models (inside OpTeamizerApp - PCL project).

If am i right ,I have a problem:
The MongoService project don't know the Models (Mobile etc.) - So how the web service can Add/ Remove / Update mobiles in database?

A little code:

**MongoService project -> MongoService.asmx:**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string InsertMobile()
    {
        MobileService mobServ = new MobileService();
        Mobile mob = new Mobile();
        mob.MobileID = 123456;
        mob.Name = "Samsung";
        mobServ .Create(mob);

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(mob);
    }
```

OpTeamizerApp project:

```
    public async Task<string> GetMobileAsync()
    {

        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        var address = $"http://URL/MongoService/MongoService.asmx/InsertMobile"; //?format=application/json";

        var response = await client.GetAsync(address);

        var mobileJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var MobileObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mobile>(mobileJson);

        return MobileObj;

    }
```

Thank you for your attention!

**UPDATE:
I can create .NET Framework Class Library with my Models and reference my Xamarin PCL & MongoService to this class library. But i cant add reference to this class library from my Xamarin PCL project**

Comment: You're on the right track; Instead of using a .NET Framework Class Library, you should keep your models in a new PCL Class Library. In VS 2017, this can be found under Cross-Platfrom > Class Library (Xamarin.Forms). You may need to fiddle with the profile, but I've used Profile111 to target both a webapi and Forms project before

Comment: I use Profile 78